# When is overclocking GPU unsafe?

Tags: gpu, overclocking

I went to AMD Radeon Software to overclock my GPU for the first time, and it said that if I damage the GPU by overclocking it they won't be responsible. So the question arises: when is overclocking a GPU unsafe?

We know that high temperature is bad for the electronic components in a GPU, but apart from that It's not clear to me what dangers there are in overclocking a GPU. For example, I've read that people who mine Ethereum with GPU, reduce the GPU core clock and voltage, so the GPU work at a relatively low temperature, but they overclock VRAM frequency. Is a very high memory frequency in a low temperature GPU safe?

Answer (score 1):

The entire philosophy of overclocking is to take something certified by a manufacturer for certain operating conditions & decide you know better than they do.
That's why it's always "unsafe" to overclock & why you immediately void the warranty.

Chipset 'speeds' are often dependant on testing processes which determine operating constraints. Different identical chips, after this test, may be certified at different speeds. This saves throwing away 'quite good' chips that don't meet ultimate spec. The upside for the customer is they get a cheap chip. The downside is that it's already known not to be able to run faster without extreme cooling measures.

Home-cooling cannot accurately allow for potential hot spots on a die … which is why the chip didn't reach faster certification [by *actual experts* in the field] in the first place.

Comment: With that said, how much of a boost you can get, entirely depends on the cooling you have